# Почему не выполняются условия if/else?

Tags: javascript, if, prompt

```
let weather='Сегодня такая замечательная погода ,не правда ли?';
let a='да';
let b='нет';
prompt(weather);
if (weather==a){alert('Как здорово что вы со мной согласны!')}
else (weather==b);{alert('Как прискорбно что вы не можете оценить красоту природы..')}
```

Comment: в чем выражается "не выполняется"? if-else всегда выполняется. Всегда! А если вам кажется, что не выполняется, значит что-то не так написано. А тут и кроме if-else достаточно ошибок.

Comment: Язык то какой - JavaScript?

Comment: язык JavaScript

Comment: Надо в метках язык ставить. Ладно, я добавил.

Comment: при вводе любого значения в модальное окно функции prompt,результат будет выражаться в всплывающем окне alert ('Как прискорбно что вы не можете оценить красоту природы..').

Comment: `prompt` возвращает результат, но вы его ничему не присваиваете. А в переменной weather так и остаётся строка с  вопросом

Comment: Да,я разобрался только что).Но всё равно спасибо за отклик!

Comment: @GiornoBonjorno, не надо полностью менять текст вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

В else не надо передавать условие, а если вам нужно сделать именно проверку на ответ нет, то надо писать else if.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно ваш код будет написан так:

```
let weather = prompt('Сегодня такая замечательная погода, не правда ли?') // берём ответ на вопрос.

if (weather === 'да') {
    alert('Как здорово, что вы со мной согласны!') // ответ на да.
} else if (weather === 'нет') { 
    alert('Как прискорбно, что вы не можете оценить красоту природы.') // ответ на нет, можно также и на другие ответы добавить else if.
} else {
    alert('Не знаю, что даже ответить.') // Если пользователь введёт что-то не то.
}
```

В итоге добавлен тот случай, если введено что-то неправильно. Мелочи, но для пользователя приятно.